How to read a 1D array from a file generated with FORTRAN using Python
I am trying to read a simple dataset to a 1D numpy array with Python.
However, the data was written with Fortran (regular ASCII) and groups repeated values together.
For example:
2*0.652384 314*0.652383 62*0.652382 48*0.652383 26*0.652384 111*0.652383
I tried using numpy.loadtxt() but it cannot read the '*' syntax.
Any help is welcome.

Is the * multiplication? Also, how many numbers are in the file?

No, the * is used to indicate repeated numbers in a sequence. Hence, [20.652384] represents [0.652384 0.652384] and [3140.652383] would represent a sequence of 314 numbers with the value 0.652383. In fact, the example I used corresponds to an array with 563 elements.

The most obvious solution would be to write to a binary file in Fortran. I just want to make sure that such a modification is not possible?

You can read in the data using normal Python machinery, split the lines on the spaces, and process the data depending on whether it has a * or not.
import numpy as np

data = []
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        p = line.split(" ")
        for term in p:
            if "*" in term:
                a, b = term.split("*")
                data.extend([float(b)]*int(a))
            else:
                data.append(float(term))

data = np.array(data)
print(data)


Here is my original answer (this does not account for the possibility of single terms without any multipliers).
One option would be to read the data in using normal Python machinery, use regex to interpret the data, create the copies, and then convert the final data array to a numpy array.
import re
import numpy as np

data = []
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        p = re.findall(r"(\d+)\*(\d+?.\d+)", line)
        for a, b in p:
            data.extend([float(b)]*int(a))

data = np.array(data)


Any way to add regular numbers in the sequence? I noticed my example is not one of the best. For instance,
8.9 20.652384 0.5 3140.652383 620.652382 480.652383 260.652384 7.77 1110.652383

I modified your answer and now it works perfectly.
data = [] with open("data.txt", "r") as f:     for line in f.readlines():         p = re.split("\s",line)         while '' in p:             p.remove('')         for el in p:             x = re.search("\*", el)             if x!=None:                 pl = re.findall(r"(\d+)\*(\d+?.\d+)", el)                 for a, b in pl:                     data.extend([float(b)]*int(a))             else:                 data.extend([float(el)]) data = np.array(data)
sorry I got lost in the formatting.

@BrunoF I've updated my answer. This version does not use regex and allows for the possibility of single terms (i.e. no multipliers).
